# Specific text parsing AFTER login

Tags: java, html, parsing, dom

I am currently trying to build a java webapp where I would have to retrieve SOME information (a few fields in a HTML table) from a page, but after login. I do have a basic java code to return the html code of a webpage, but what I am looking for is to be able to Log in, and then parse the text from a URL (certain HTML fields), which otherwise would not be accessible. I have looked into tools like Selenium WebDriver and jTidy, but could not find what I was looking for.

Example code I use to get HTML code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

public class WebCrawler{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            URL google = new URL("http://stackoverflow.com");
            URLConnection yc = google.openConnection();
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(yc.getInputStream()));
            String inputLine;
            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(inputLine);

            }
            in.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Trying this right now [link](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-automate-login-a-website-java-example/)

Comment: You might give jsoup a look.  http://jsoup.org/